# Why cant I get my Regular expression working?

Tags: javascript, regex

What am I doing wrong as both strings below are returning `false` when tested below?

```
    var pattern = "^[\s\da-zA-ZåäöÅÄÖ_]+$"
    var reg = new RegExp(pattern);

    console.log(reg.test("This should be invalid as it is full with invalid chars. #!¤%&/()=?"));
    console.log(reg.test("This is an valid string, despite that Swedish chars such as ÅÄÖ are used"));
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to double-up on the backslashes in the pattern.

```
var pattern = "^[\\s\\da-zA-ZåäöÅÄÖ_]+$"
```

The problem is that when you build regular expression objects that way, there are *two* passes made over the string: one to interpret it as a string, and then a second to interpret it as a regular expression. Both of those micro-syntaxes use `\` to mean something, so by doubling them you get a single backslash out of the string constant parse.

If your pattern is really a constant, and not something that you construct dynamically from separate parts, then you can just use the native syntax for regular expressions:

```
var pattern = /^[\s\da-zA-ZåäöÅÄÖ_]+$/;
```

Only one backslash is necessary because the pattern is only parsed once, as a regular expression.

Comment: Hi Pointy. Never knew there were two passes. However I still get `false` returned from both call to `reg.test` as shown above unfortunately, using your patterns

Comment: @Industrial there's a comma in your second test string.

Comment: Damn! I need new glasses. Thanks a lot, Pointy